# Pollard Rho Optimization

Tags: elliptic-curves, attack, pollard-rho

One of the most important attacks on Elliptic Curve cryptography is Pollard's Rho method. The effect on security can be seen on [SafeCurves](http://safecurves.cr.yp.to/rho.html).

This attack is pretty old and there has been a bunch of optimizations. Some of them are listed [here on page 8](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/605.pdf#page=8).

My question is: What is the newest/best optimization for the Pollard's Rho attack? Is there a paper, which contains all (significant) optimizations?